# Show/Hide divs depending on the result of the JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, css, dom, show

I have 5 hidden divs that can only be shown if the object items are true.

```
    .colors{
      display: none;
    }
```

```
 <div class="colors" id="blue">BLUE</div>
 <div class="colors" id="red">RED</div>
 <div class="colors" id="green">GREEN</div>
 <div class="colors" id="yellow">YELLOW</div>
```

```
var colors = { blue:false, red:false, green:true, yellow:true};


var colorsTrue = Object.keys(colors).filter((key)=> {
    return colors[key] !== false; 
});
```

After filtering all true items, how do I show only the corresponding divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DOM selector](http://JavaScript%20HTML%20DOM%20-%20Changing%20CSS) to change the css of each div depending of the value of the color:

```js
var colors = {
  blue: false,
  red: false,
  green: true,
  yellow: true
};


Object.keys(colors).forEach(key => {
  document.getElementById(key).style.display = colors[key] ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
.colors {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors" id="blue">BLUE</div>
<div class="colors" id="red">RED</div>
<div class="colors" id="green">GREEN</div>
<div class="colors" id="yellow">YELLOW</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Filtering method to this

```
for(let key in colors) {
    if(colors[key] == true) {
    document.getElementById(key).style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

Check on JsBin https://jsbin.com/gotiqaq/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

This will work: Iterate through properties and change the id style to block if the key is true.

```
var colors = { blue: false, red: false, green: true, yellow: true };

for (var color in colors) {
    if (colors.hasOwnProperty(color)) {
        if(colors[color]) {
          document.querySelector(`#${color}`).style.display='block'
        }
    }
}
```